# Meteor AutoForm hooks not firing, and getting ec.invalidKeys is not a function errors

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform

Throughout my entire app, I've tried to use autoform multiple times, but I think there is a real conflict between autoform and MaterializeCSS templates. Anyhow, I have been getting the following errors:

Schema:

```
import SimpleSchema from 'simpl-schema';
import { Materials } from '/imports/api/materials/materials.js';
import { PurchasesAPI } from '/imports/api/purchases/api.js';

import '../../ui/components/purchasing/purchasing-autocomplete-list-template.html';

export const purchasingCreatePurchaseSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  userId: {
    type: String,
    autoValue: function () {
      if (this.isInsert) {
        console.log("this is insert");
        console.log(Meteor.userId());
        return Meteor.userId();
      } else if (this.isUpsert) {
        return { $setOnInsert: Meteor.userId() };
      }

      this.unset(); // Prevent user from supplying their own value
      return undefined;
    },
    autoform: {
      omit: true
    }
  },
  createdOn: {
    type: Date,
    // defaultValue: new Date(),
    autoValue: function () {
      if (this.isInsert) {
        return new Date();
      }
      this.unset(); // Prevent user from supplying their own value
      return undefined;
    },
    autoform: {
      omit: true
    }
  },
  purchaseOrderNo: {
    type: String,
    autoValue: function () {
      if (this.isInsert) {
        return PurchasesAPI.newPurchaseOrder();
      }
      this.unset(); // Prevent user from supplying their own value
      return undefined;
    }
  },
  orderedDate: {
    type: Date,
    autoform: {
      afFieldInput: {
        class: 'datepicker'
      }
    }
  },
  supplier: {
    type: String,
    defaultValue: "Not Specified"
  },
  material: {
    type: String,
    autoform: {
      afFieldInput: {
        type: 'autocomplete-input',
        placeholder: 'Material',
        settings: function () {
          return {
            position: "top",
            limit: 20,
            rules: [
              {
                collection: Materials,
                field: "material",
                matchAll: true,
                template: Template.Purchasing_material_item
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  orderConfirmationDate: {
    type: Date,
    optional: true,
    autoform: {
      afFieldInput: {
        class: 'datepicker'
      }
    }
  },
  estimatedTimeOfArrival: {
    type: Date,
    optional: true,
    autoform: {
      afFieldInput: {
        class: 'datepicker'
      }
    }
  },
  actualTimeOfArrival: {
    type: Date,
    optional: true,
    autoform: {
      afFieldInput: {
        class: 'datepicker'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

HTML

```
{{> quickForm schema=createPurchaseSchema id="createNewPurchase" type="normal" buttonContent="false"}}
```

When the submit button is pressed, I'm getting:

```
VM32227 aldeed_autoform.js:7702 Uncaught TypeError: ec.invalidKeys is not a function
    at failedValidation (VM32227 aldeed_autoform.js:7702)
    at Object.autoFormSubmitHandler (VM32227 aldeed_autoform.js:7836)
    at VM32193 blaze.js:3775
    at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (VM32193 blaze.js:3744)
    at Blaze.View.<anonymous> (VM32193 blaze.js:3774)
    at VM32193 blaze.js:2617
    at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (VM32193 blaze.js:2271)
    at Blaze._DOMRange.<anonymous> (VM32193 blaze.js:2616)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (VM32193 blaze.js:863)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (VM32156 modules.js:17882)
failedValidation @ VM32227 aldeed_autoform.js:7702
autoFormSubmitHandler @ VM32227 aldeed_autoform.js:7836
(anonymous) @ VM32193 blaze.js:3775
Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc @ VM32193 blaze.js:3744
(anonymous) @ VM32193 blaze.js:3774
(anonymous) @ VM32193 blaze.js:2617
Blaze._withCurrentView @ VM32193 blaze.js:2271
(anonymous) @ VM32193 blaze.js:2616
(anonymous) @ VM32193 blaze.js:863
dispatch @ VM32156 modules.js:17882
elemData.handle @ VM32156 modules.js:17690
Navigated to http://localhost:3000/purchasing/purchases/new-purchase?purchaseOrderNo=&orderedDate=&supplier=Not+Specified&material=&orderConfirmationDate=&estimatedTimeOfArrival=&actualTimeOfArrival=
```

My hooks are not firing either, if I try to overwrite the submit button with `Template.Purchasing_new_purchase_form.events({ 'submit' : function() {...} })` It does not work either.

If someone can help me with this I'd be immensely grateful and hopefully I can start using more autoforms in my app, but currently I have simply coded the form from scratch, then apply manual validation without reactive validation. Is this an inherent problem with AutoForm or just something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of autoform (and which collection2-core, and SimpleSchema) are you using?

Comment: @Jankapunkt `"aldeed:autoform 5.8.1*, "simpl-schema": "^0.3.2" `, and `mpowaga:autoform-autocomplete`     0.0.2' , not using `collection2-core`.

Comment: The way you hook the event may not be wrong, but I am curious what happens if you do it like: `'submit #createNewPurchase' : function() {...}` where you basically specify the id of the form to the event map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to resolve this issue!

I updated `Autoform to 6.3.0`, `Simple-schema` to > 1.4, removed all other related autoform packages like `autocomplete`, and `autoform-materialize` and got things to work.